Spring-boot undertow access log retention policy
How should I set retention period for spring boot undertow server access logs? From documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html I can see properties to set access log config only. Is there a way we can specify how many access log files will be retained?

No, there isn't. The access log writing and rotation is performed by Undertow's DefaultAccessLogReceiver. It does not support limiting the number of logs files that are retained.
